# Dataset not found in my namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am creating a Visual C# Forms application in visual studio, and I am trying to use a data set. I have imported the data set using the wizard, and also used it in a data grid, yet when I debug the program, it gives me these errors:

```
1>C:\Users\danie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VIAdmin\VIAdmin\home.Designer.cs(219,25,219,37): error CS0426: The type name 'staffDataSet' does not exist in the type 'VIAdmin'
1>C:\Users\danie\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\VIAdmin\VIAdmin\home.Designer.cs(221,25,221,50): error CS0426: The type name 'staffDataSetTableAdapters' does not exist in the type 'VIAdmin'
```

I am not sure why it is doing this, as I am able to see all of the columns in the designer when I am not running it. I have tried declaring it like

```
private DataSet staffDataSet;
```

But VS then tells me it is already defined?

If it is any help, I am using VS 2015 Community

Comment: The errors point to specific lines in your designer.cs file. What do you have on those lines?

Comment: `private VIAdmin.staffDataSet staffDataSet;` and `private VIAdmin.staffDataSetTableAdapters.StaffTableAdapter staffTableAdapter;`